# Replacing strings in all images' SRCs

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, replace, src

Hi I'm using a wordpress slider plugin called soliloquy.

Currently on the desktop everything's great. but on mobile the images take up so much memory it crashes safari.

i'm using modernizr to detect if it's a touch device then replace the src string from

```
name.jpg
```

(original size uploaded image) to

```
name-480x480.jpg
```

(the smaller image)

my code now is

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
$('img.soliloquy-item-image').each(function(index, element) {
$(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg', '-480x480.jpg'));
});
```

this apparently only replaces the first image and not all. anyone knwo why?

Comment: Have you thought about using css media queries?  One problem you may run into is tablets are tough devices and I am sure you don't want a 480x480 image on a device that supports something much larger. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

From quick look in the source, the plugin is using jQuery data attribute `soliloquy-src` so try replacing that as well:

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
    $('img.soliloquy-item-image').each(function(index, element) {
        var img = $(this);
        img.attr("src", img.attr("src").replace(".jpg", "-480x480.jpg"));
        img.data("soliloquy-src", img.data("soliloquy-src").replace(".jpg", "-480x480.jpg"));
    });
}
```